# sequences inequalities

Tags: sequences-and-series

Assume that $(s_k)$ is a sequence of non - negative real numbers, $s_1\le 1$ and for all $k\ge 1$ fulfills the following inequality
$s_{k+1}\le 2k+3 \sum\limits_{j=1}^{k}s_j$
Show that, $s_k <7^k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 0):

Use induction. Assume the claim is valid for some $k\ge1$. Then
$$
\begin{split}
s_{k+1} &\le 2k + 3\sum_{j=1}^k s_j < 2k + 3\sum_{j=1}^k 7^j\\
& = 2k + 3 \left(\frac{7^{k+1}-1 }{7-1}-7\right)= 2k + \frac12 7^{k+1}-\frac72.
\end{split}$$
It remains to prove $4k - 7 \le 7^{k+1}$, which is easy.